# Permutations of alphabet with X following Y *and* vowels in alphabetical order

Tags: combinatorics

**Exercise**

> Find the number of arrangements of the $26$ letters of the English alphabet that have both
>
> - Y occurring before X
> - all $5$ vowels (A, E, I, O, U) occurring in alphabetical order

---

**Warm-up**

First I count how many arrangements meet the first condition. Probably not necessary, but I am wondering if I am using the right reasoning. Such an arrangement would look like

$$\begin{matrix}[\alpha \text{ of 24 letters}] & \text{Y} & [\beta \text{ of }24-\alpha\text{ letters}] & X & [\gamma \text{ of }24-\alpha-\beta\text{ letters}]\end{matrix}$$

I think the number of permutations of the letters surrounding Y and X will then be

$$\sum_{\alpha=0}^{24} \alpha! \binom{24}\alpha \sum_{\beta=0}^{24-\alpha} \beta! \binom{24-\alpha}\beta \sum_{\gamma=0}^{24-\alpha-\beta} \gamma! \binom{24-\alpha-\beta}\gamma = 506\,809\,361\,586\,340\,667\,433\,417\,385$$

By extension, an arrangement in which the vowels are alphabetized might look like

$$\begin{matrix}[\alpha \text{ consonants}] & \text{A} & [\beta \text{ consonants}] & \text{E} & [\gamma \text{ consonants}] & \text{I} & [\delta \text{ consonants}] & \text{O} & [\epsilon \text{ consonants}] & \text{U} & [\phi \text{ consonants}]\end{matrix}$$

with a total count of

$$\sum_{\alpha=0}^{21} \alpha! \binom{21}\alpha \sum_{\beta=0}^{21-\alpha} \beta! \binom{21-\alpha}\beta \sum_{\gamma=0}^{21-\alpha-\beta} \gamma! \binom{21-\alpha-\beta}\gamma \sum_{\delta=0}^{21-\alpha-\beta-\gamma} \delta! \binom{21-\alpha-\beta-\gamma}\delta \sum_{\epsilon=0}^{21-\alpha-\beta-\gamma-\delta} \epsilon! \binom{21-\alpha-\beta-\gamma-\delta}\epsilon \sum_{\phi=0}^{21-\alpha-\beta-\gamma-\delta-\epsilon} \phi! \binom{21-\alpha-\beta-\gamma-\delta-\epsilon}\phi = 11\,369\,881\,057\,625\,718\,121\,105$$

> Am I counting these individual arrangements correctly?

> Is there a more elegant way of counting them?

---

**Possible solution**

In the sum for the second count above, replace $21$ with $19$. Then multiply the resulting sum by the number of ways one can tack on Y and X to the arrangement. For a given alphabetical-vowel arrangement, Y can be placed in $25$ different positions. If we place Y at the $k$-th position $(1\le k\le25)$, then that leaves $26-k$ possible positions for X. The total number of ways to do this would be

$$25 \sum_{k=1}^{25} (26-k) = 8\,125$$

Then the total number of arrangements satisfying both criteria is

$$92\,380\,283\,593\,208\,959\,733\,978\,125$$

> Is this count correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The total number of permutations is $26!$. Those where X follows Y are exactly half of them.

Now consider two permutations where X follows Y *equivalent* if they only differ for the position of the vowels. This defines an equivalence relation in which each class has precisely $5!$ elements and only one permutation in each equivalence class has the vowels in alphabetical order.

Thus the total number is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{26!}{5!}=1\,680\,381\,088\,027\,523\,481\,600\,000
$$

You get the same result if you use *[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two)*. You want first to distribute the $21$ consonants (in alphabetical order) in six bins, which can well be empty: some (maybe zero) consonants before *a*, some (maybe zero) between *a* and *e* and so on.

The total number of possible distributions is
$$
\binom{21+6-1}{6-1}=\binom{26}{5}=\frac{26!}{5!\,21!}
$$
Now in any distribution you can permute the consonants freely in $21!$ ways, but at the end only half of them will have X after Y. Thus you get
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{26!}{5!\,21!}21!
$$
as before.

Answer (score 3):

Choose two of the $26$ positions in the alphabet for $X$ and $Y$.  There is only one way to place them in those positions so that $X$ follows $Y$.  Choose five of the remaining $26 - 2 = 24$ positions for the five vowels.  There is only one way to arrange the vowels in the selected positions so that they appear in alphabetical order.  Then arrange the remaining $19$ letters in the remaining $19$ positions.  Thus, there are
$$\binom{26}{2}\binom{24}{5}19!$$
arrangements of the alphabet that have $Y$ occurring before $X$ in which the vowels occur in alphabetical order, which does not agree with your count.

Comment: Are you counting the arrangements with the exact substring AEIOU? I took the criterion to mean we can have any number of letters occurring between each vowel, so long as the vowels themselves are in order.

Comment: I am counting all arrangements in which the vowels appear in alphabetical order, which is why I chose five of the remaining $24$ positions for the vowels.  You will notice that egreg's answer agrees with mine.

Answer (score 2):

Permutation problems can often be simplified *hugely* by making judicious use of probabilities. Here it simplifies to a one line answer, viz

[All permutations]$\times$ **P**[Y before X]$\times$  **P**[Vowels in alphabetical order]$\;=26!\cdot{\dfrac1{2!}\cdot\dfrac1{5!}}$